# ServiceStack Authentication Return Custom Response

Tags: authentication, servicestack, servicestack-bsd

I'm implementing a custom `CredentialsAuthProvider` in ServiceStack and it works great. My only problem is that I would like to return more information back in my `AuthResponse`. I'm using the following override to authenticate in my custom provider:

```cs
public override bool TryAuthenticate(ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
{
    // Authenticates user and adds values to session
}
```

The response I get after successful authentication is the out of the box response that the Auth plugin provides. Is there a way to add more values or to customize the response upon successful login? I don't see any overrides that would allow it.

Comment: I think your question might be answered by this question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117469/how-can-i-extend-servicestack-authentication

Comment: That's not exactly the same as what I'm trying to do, but thanks for the suggestion. I ended up making a separate call after authentication to get the properties I need from the SS session.

Comment: How about this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280319/return-a-custom-auth-response-object-from-servicestack-authentication :)