# Returning custom auth response with ServiceStack

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, servicestack

Hello service stack users -

The TL;DR version of the upcoming question is this: How do I return a custom auth response when authenticating with Servicestack?

I've examined a few previous Stack question/answers about this topic, but I haven't quite been able to come up with the best way to do this:

[How can I extend ServiceStack Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117469/how-can-i-extend-servicestack-authentication/11118747#11118747) **and** [Return a custom auth response object from ServiceStack authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280319/return-a-custom-auth-response-object-from-servicestack-authentication)

I'd like to return this object from ServiceStack to a remote JsonServiceClient:

```
public class MyGreatCustomAuthResponse : AuthResponse
{
    public UserModel UserModel { get; set; }
}
```

I do have a client currently working with the default auth response. I do that in this manner:

```
var AuthResponse = client.Post(new Auth
{
    provider = "credentials",
    UserName = user.user_id, 
    Password = user.password,
    RememberMe = true
});
```

I assumed the way to accept a custom response might look something like this:

```
var AuthResponse = client.Post<MyGreatCustomResponse>(new CustomAuthRequest
{
    provider = "credentials",
   UserName = user.user_id, 
   Password = user.password,
    RememberMe = true
});
//Use the UserModel object in the response for some other function on the client
var UserModel = AuthResponse.UserModel ;
```

Is that something that is easily possible? If so, how might one start to code this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In v3 other than taking a copy and customizing of the built-in [AuthService](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/v3/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/AuthService.cs) you can add additional metadata by appending custom HTTP Headers using a [Global](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters) or [Response Filter Attribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Filter-attributes).

In the next v4 release, we've added a `Dictionary<string, string> Meta` to the [Authentication and Registration Response DTOs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Client/AuthDtos.cs#L39) so you can use the response filters to add metadata directly in the Response DTOs.

**Sample Code**

```
 this.GlobalResponseFilters.Add((req, res, responseDto) =>
        {
            if (res.Dto.GetType() == typeof(AuthenticateResponse))
            {
                CustomUserSession cs = (CustomUserSession)req.GetSession();
                Dictionary<string, string> otherData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                otherData.Add("CustomData", cs.CustomData.ToString());
                ((AuthenticateResponse)res.Dto).Meta = otherData;
            }
        });
```