# In custom CredentialsAuthProvider, on successfull authenticate I want to send additional data in Meta property

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, servicestack

In custom CredentialsAuthProvider, on successfull authenticate I want to send additional data in Meta property. Where can I get current response and add info to meta? I want to do this in `OnAuthenticated` method because I have some more logic for authenticated users and then send meta. This is not session data, only one time thing for logged in users.

This is an [Existing Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280319/return-a-custom-auth-response-object-from-servicestack-authentication), but it is approx 4 years old and not sure if it will have any impact on already authenticated users like mentioned in the comments. Also this SO suggests to override `Authenticate` method which doesn't apply for me as I want to perform only for authenticated users in `OnAuthenticated` Event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the `AuthenticateResponse` by having your AuthProvider implement [IAuthResponseFilter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/0672a71eac3cf815d71874d408572285135da031/src/ServiceStack/Auth/IAuthProvider.cs#L46) which gets called with an `AuthFilterContext` on successful Authentication that lets you modify the response with:

```
public void Execute(AuthFilterContext authContext)
{
    authContext.AuthResponse.Meta = new Dictionary<string,string> { ... };
}
```

Another option is to override `Authenticate` in your AuthProvider, e.g:

```
public override object Authenticate(
    IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, Authenticate request)
{
    var response = base.Authenticate(authService, session, request);
    if (response is AuthenticateResponse authDto)
    {
        authDto.Meta = new Dictionary<string,string> { ... }
    }
    return response;
}
```

Alternatively as it's just a normal Service you could also register a [Global Response Filter](http://docs.servicestack.net/request-and-response-filters) to modify the Response DTO, e.g:

```
GlobalResponseFilters.Add((req, res, responseDto) => 
{
    if (responseDto is AuthenticateResponse authDto)
    {
        authDto.Meta = new Dictionary<string,string> { ... }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you mythz. I'll try this and let you know. thanks once agian. ah, the servicestack guy on SO ;)